# How do you check for blank lines in a file and then ignore them in Java?

Tags: java, file

I've seen similar questions asked about how to find a blank line. I know how to find a blank line, but the sheer nature of finding it retrieves it and screws up the rest of your code.

Consider the following while loop:

```
while(file.hasNextLine()){
    if(file.nextLine.equals("")){
        continue;
    }
    String[] words = file.nextLine().split(" ");
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        System.out.print(words[i]);
    }
}
```

The idea here is to say, if there is a blank line, skip this iteration and move to the next line only extracting words. But just checking to see if the line is blank retrieves the next line (blank or not) and then retrieves the FOLLOWING line and stores it in words.

What is the proper way to find blank lines without actually retrieving 'nextLine' to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `file.nextLine()`, but store it in a variable before checking it for emptiness. That way you'll only call it once per iteration.

```
while(file.hasNextLine()){
    final String line = file.nextLine();
    if(line.isEmpty()){
        continue;
    }
    String[] words = line.split(" ");
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        System.out.print(words[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, no worries, it's early here, still got energy ;) @Joop: Thanks for the edit, it was just before my edit though.